# Android Firebase authentication issue

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to login with Firebase authentication but I'm getting a FirebaseException. In my activity I have the onCreate method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle(R.string.title_calendar);
        initData();

    }
```

The onStart method:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            // something
        } else {
            signIn();
        }
    }
```

and the signIn method:

```
private void signIn() {
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword("test@abc.com", "123456789").addOnSuccessListener(this, new  OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                Log.i("Log", "signIn:SUCCESS");
            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        Log.e("Log", "signIn:FAILURE", exception);
                    }
                });
    }
```

I'm getting this:

```
E/shinseiLog: signIn:FAILURE
    com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Identity Toolkit API has not been used in project 611854850952 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/overview?project=611854850952 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry. ]
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.jz.zzK(Unknown Source:147)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.jb.zza(Unknown Source:12)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.kj.zzL(Unknown Source:11)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.kl.onFailure(Unknown Source:35)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.kb.onTransact(Unknown Source:79)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
```

the authentication method email, password is enabled on firebase console and also Identity Toolkit API.

Comment: did u use fire base assistant from android studio??

Comment: The error states that you've not enabled sign In using this method. You've to first go to your project in firebase and turn on the method you're trying to login through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Check Your Project Existing firebase console using following URL
[https://console.firebase.google.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GHdf.png) 
If is it available rebuild your project using
Build -> Rebuild Project
and Resync your project using Gradle Files

[Sync With GradleFiles Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GHdf.png)

Comment: Thanks, all authentication method were already enabled. After the rebuild the authentication succeeded.

Comment: Welcome!,its my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

Is your google-services.json file from Firebase up to date? As you enable services in Firebase that JSON gets updates. Try re-downloading it from Firebase and check if it is different?